# Running and killing servers and watchers from a bash script

Tags: bash, shell, subprocess

For a webapp I am developing, I have a bash script to watch for changes in the source and update the running environment.

```
function app-serve {
    python runserver.py
}

function compile-coffee {
    inotifywait -e modity scripts | while read change; do
        coffee -o js scripts
    done
}
```

Now, I need these two functions run simultaneously,

```
app-serve &
compile-coffee &
```

And wait, too

```
wait
```

The problem is, when I want to stop these processes, a simple `Ctrl-C` isn't doing it. When I do a `Ctrl-C`, I get the command prompt back, but the processes run in the functions are still alive.

Is there a way to tell bash to just wait until I hit `Ctrl-C`, and then kill all the subprocesses?

**Edit**: One clarification, I see the `python` process I start in `app-serve` function *is* killed. Only the `inotifywait` and a couple of `bash` processes are dangling.

Answer (score 1):

You can catch the ctrl-c signal in your bash script and have it execute a function that finds the processes and kills them.

See http://hacktux.com/bash/control/c

Probably something like killall app-server  and  killall compile-coffee.

Don't forget to exit the bash script with a call to exit.

Comment: Nice. Thanks for the information on trapping. But, I'd like to find the pids and kill them, instead of `killall`. Also, when I give the function name to `killall`, it says `app-server: no process found`.